# An uninvited visitor file 'mbox'

Tags: cron

I check the home directory and find a  extra files 'mbox'

```
me@alpha:~$ ls -l | grep 'mbox' | sed "s/$USER/me/g"
-rw-------  1 me me   315392 Jan 19 23:10 mbox
-rw-r--r--  1 me me        0 Jan 19 23:10 mbox.lock
```

I did not create such a file intentially

```
me@alpha:~$ cat mbox | head -10 | sed "s/$USER/me/g"
From me@alpha  Sun Jan 13 16:15:01 2019
Return-Path: <me@alpha>
X-Original-To: me
Delivered-To: me@alpha
Received: by alpha (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id D805C2C0FBE; Sun, 13 Jan 2019 16:15:01 +0800 (CST)
From: root@alpha (Cron Daemon)
To: me@alpha
Subject: Cron <me@alpha> (cd ~/Documents/OrgMode; git add .; git commit -m "defensive save")
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

All the cron logs are stored in

```
me@alpha:~$ cat /var/mail/$USER | head -10 | sed "s/$USER/me/g"
From me@alpha  Wed Jan 16 11:25:01 2019
Return-Path: <me@alpha>
X-Original-To: me
Delivered-To: me@alpha
Received: by alpha (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id D40C52C1345; Wed, 16 Jan 2019 11:25:01 +0800 (CST)
From: root@alpha (Cron Daemon)
To: me@alpha
Subject: Cron <me@alpha> (cd ~/Documents/OrgMode; git add .; git commit -m "defensive save")
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

mbox is a redundancy

How could I check where the mbox come from?

Comment: Not an answer, but just so you know, there's no reason to do `cat file | head` ([UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)), you can always do `head file` directly instead.